# How to add TextField by pressing button in C# and WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add a Textfield to my Form in C#, when I press a button.

```
####################
|   ______         |
|  [__ADD_]        |
|__________________|

####################
|   ______         |
|  |  TF  |        |
|  |______|        |
|   ______         |
|  [__ADD_]        |
|__________________|
```

This is, how my Program mainly should look, before and after pressing the Button.
Right now I'm approaching the Problem like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    int i = 0;
    TextBox[] t = new TextBox[80];
    Button[] b = new Button[80];

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        t[i] = new TextBox();
        b[i] = new Button();
        i++;
    }

}
```

So actually, I'm allready creating the Fields, but I can't show them.

**How do I show them?**

Comment: Indexes in C# are 0-based; so you should start `i` at `0`.

Comment: 1. Open form designer file and you can find how it is done. 2. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319266

Comment: Oh, yeah... I know... Forgot to mention, but the first one (index 0) will be loaded statically at the beginning. But yeah, you are right!

Comment: @Reniuz: I am not trying to use Windows Forms. I need to do it in WPF

Comment: Oh yeah I spotted that later, sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your textboxes, you have to set their coordinates(x,y) and dimensions(width,height) or, if you are using a grid or stackpanel add them.

```
t[i] = new TextBox();
t[i].Text = "new textbox";
t[i].textBox2.Name = "textBox1";

Grid1.Children.Add(t[i]);
//or SomeStackPanel.Children.Add(t[i]);
```

in this case i added the textbox to a grid, but you can add them also to a stackpanel, etc, etc.